# How spark manages its memory

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm new to Spark and am trying to treat csv files(more than 1000/sec) in spark streaming,each file contains approximately 50,000 line.If my memory is full, and the files are still coming.
How spark reacts?
And what their file management system (FIFO,...)?
how I can know which are the treated files and which have yet?

Comment: This is generally a broad question. But Spark can spill things to disk once it runs out of memory. This can affect performance of your streaming data, but will still make it possible to process the data.

Comment: Yes, you can. You set it via Spark Configuration parameters. [See this page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: thank you for your help, I have one last question: in Spark Streaming is it possible to make one repetitive treatment?   for example, I make a treatment on files in streaming to have a resultat A (a1, a2. . . ), and every 1 hour I have a resultat B = sum of (ai) generated in the last hour